# Refresh part of website

Tags: jquery, refresh

I want to refresh a div just like when you press F5. I don't want to place new content inside the div, I just want to reload it. Is is possible?

I don't need to user jquery/ajax to pull data from anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refresh happens every time a screen redraws (50-60Hz)... not sure what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have a script with a src but it only loads when the page is loaded for the first time and I can't force it to run. I had the idea of refreshing the div in order to see if the script reloads too.

Comment: The question is why do you need to reload a script?

Comment: Because it does not load. A script like this one <script src="whatever"></script> is loaded ONLY when the page loads and not by ajax, etc. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's getScript method.

```
$.getScript( "script.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
 console.log( data ); // Data returned
 console.log( textStatus ); // Success
 console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
 console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```

See more on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/.

Comment: but the script is in this format: <script type='text/javascript' src='http://********'></script> How can I save it like script and do what you suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what you want, but you could put whatever is inside your script into a function, and call it anytime you need it. It's much easier to do than the whole refresh thing (and the refresh won't reload your script). Like this:

```
function my_script() {
    // contents of your script here...
}

my_script(); // this runs the script and you can use it from the console as well, after the page as loaded
```

Comment: I can't place a script inside that function :/ Like this <script src="src"></script> so it is not useful for me...

Comment: And you can't change the src script?

Comment: No because it is given by a website. If I change it, it won't work. <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ads1.qadabra.com/t?asdasdasdasdsad'></script> It is similar to this.

Comment: Then you should probably check the ads documentation and see if they give an option to call multiple instances.

Comment: They dont give any documentation, they just give the script.